# Count the number of ways N queens can be placed on an N✕N chess board

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, backtracking, n-queens

The n-queens puzzle is the problem of placing n queens on an n✕n chessboard such that no two queens attack each other.

Given an integer n, this code returns the number of distinct solutions to the n-queens puzzle.

How can I further optimize (in time and space) the solution below to leetcode's N-Queens 2 problem? This solution has a runtime of 8 ms, beating 42.55% of submissions, and consumes 6 MB of memory, outperforming 82.99% of all submissions. I believe there should be a way to improve the performance but I am struggling to implement the requisite modifications.

```
class Solution {
public:
     typedef pair<int,int> ii;

    void solveNQtrav(int N, int row, vector<ii>& Pos, int& ct){
        if(N == row){
            ++ct;
        }
        
        for(int col = 0; col < N; ++col){
            bool safe = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < row; ++j){
                if(Pos[j].second == col||Pos[j].first-Pos[j].second == row-col
                ||Pos[j].first+Pos[j].second == row+col){
                    safe = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(safe){
                Pos[row] = ii(row, col);
                solveNQtrav(N, row+1, Pos, ct);
            }
        }
    }

    int totalNQueens(int n) {
        vector<ii> pos(n);
        int count = 0;
        solveNQtrav(n, 0, pos, count);
        return count;
    }
};
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted Leetcode's text for the question as a quote.

Comment: It is possible to improve the speed by using symetries. For example, the number of solutions with a queen at first column on first row is same as with a queen at last row. I provided a simple solution on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653648/10553341). However, I don't know if this (rather old) proposal is as optimised as yours.

Comment: The reclusive call in `solveNQtrav` is not a tail call. If you can change it to a tail call (maybe add another function?) that could provide a substantial optimisation.

Comment: Is it possible to implement tail recursion in this problem (my initial attempts were unsuccessful)? How substantial of an improvement could be gained in runtime, doesn't tail recursion primarily impact space complexity?

Answer (score 3):

## Optimizing the code

Given that the LeetCode site mentions that \$1 \leq n \leq 9\$, the optimal solution would be to precalculate the solution:

```
#include <array>

class Solution {
public:
    int totalNQueens(int n) {
        return std::array{1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 10, 4, 40, 92, 352}[n];
    }
};
```

This uses no heap memory at all and should only need a few CPU cycles to execute.

If you think this is against the spirit of LeetCode, then consider making your solution `constexpr`, so you can then build an array with the solutions at compile time. That way you are calculating the values programmatically, but have the benefit of the executable just doing a simple table lookup.

## Naming things

Some names of types and variables are unnecessarily short, like `ii` and `ct`. You are also not consistent: why is there `ct` and `count`, `pos` and `Pos`, `n` and `N`?

Names should be concise, but not unnecessarily abbreviated, so prefer `count` instead of `ct`. Only use one- or two-letter variable names for things that are very common, like `n` for "number", or `i` for a loop index.

Instead of `ii`, I would use `position` or `coordinates`.

Also use a name that describes what a variable is used for rather than just describing the type of data it holds. So instead of `pos`, maybe `queens` or `queen_positions` would be better, as this vector holds the positions of the queens on the board.

## Prefer creating a `struct` instead of using `std::pair`

It's much nicer to create a `struct` than to use `std::pair` or `std::tuple`. The advantage of a struct is that you can name the individual values it holds. So for example:

```
struct position {
    int row;
    int col;
};
```

Allows you to write code like:

```
void solveNQtrav(int n, int row, std::vector<position>& queens, int& count) {
    …
    if (queens[j].col == col ||
        queens[j].row - queens[j].col == row - col ||
        queens[j].row + queens[j].col == row + col) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

So now you don't have to remember anymore if `.first` is the row or the column.

## Create helper functions to reduce code complexity

The `if`-statement in `solveNQtrav()` looks quite complex, and if you don't already know what it is supposed to do it is hard to figure out what it means. Even for small amounts of code it sometimes helps to create a helper function:

```
bool attacks(position queen, position pos) {
    return queen.col == pos.col ||
           queen.row - queen.col == pos.row - pos.col ||
           queen.row + queen.col == pos.row + pos.col;
}

void solveNQtrav(int n, int row, std::vector<position>& queens, int& count) {
    …
    if (attacks(queens[j], {row, col}) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Now if I read the `if`-statement, it's almost self-documenting that it checks if the given queen attacks the given position. You could create more helper functions as well, like one that checks if a given column is safe to place a queen, so you can write:

```
void solveNQtrav(int n, int row, std::vector<position>& queens, int& count) {
    if (n == row) {
        ++count;
    }
        
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        if (column_is_safe(queens, row, col)) {
              queens[row] = {row, col};
              solveNQtrav(n, row + 1, queens, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Arguments and return value

You don't need to pass `n` to `solveNQtrav`; the vector of positions already knows its size, so you can use that. Furthermore,
you can make `solveNQtrav()` `return` the number of solutions instead of using a reference parameter. Finally, you can make `row` the last parameter and give it a default value:

```
int solveNQtrav(std::vector<position>& queens, int row = 0) {
    if (queens.size() == row) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    int count = 0;
 
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        if (column_is_safe(queens, row, col)) {
              queens[row] = {row, col};
              count += solveNQtrav(n, row + 1, queens, count);
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

This simplified `totalNQueens()`:

```
int totalNQueens(int n) {
    vector<position> queens(n);
    return solveNQtrav(queens);
}
```

## You didn't need a vector of `std::pair` to begin with

Consider that the vector of positions of the queens is laid out such that the queen on row \$i\$ is always at index \$i\$, you didn't need to store the row number in the vector at all; a simple vector of `int`s storing just the columns each queen appears in would have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

Code is incomplete.  I infer that somewhere you have

```
#include <pair>
#include <vector>

using std::pair;
using std::vector;
```

I don't think the `using`s add any value (they don't even make the code smaller).  I recommend dropping them and simply using the qualified typenames in your code.  That makes life easier for readers, too, as they don't have to hold so much context.

---

It's not clear why the innards of the class are all exposed (`public`).  For that matter, there doesn't seem to be any need for a class at all: it holds no state, and the two functions could equally well be free functions (or, almost equivalently, `static`).